# htaccess. redirect index.php/foo url rewriting

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

i see it more accurate to use a soft 302 redirect for index.php (rather than 301 moved permanently status) as this way it gives a found status but then again still redirects to the domain correct.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php$ /$1 [L,R=302,NC,NE]
```

the above rule redirects only index.php to the domain.., But it also would be nice (to hit 2 birds with 1 stone) by including index.php/foo or index.php/foo/widget urls to reditect too.

i am working on this but it doesn't seem to function correctly

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php/$ /$1 [L,R=302,NC,NE]
```

Comment: clarify source and destination URLs in both cases. See also [`AcceptPathInfo`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo)

Comment: Can anyone please suggest ..?

Comment: this example works dandy, 
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php(.*?)$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]

it redirects everything that has index.php (no matter if followed by anything).